# Random-access Zip file without writing it to disk

Tags: java, zip

I have a 1-2GB zip file with 500-1000k entries. I need to get files by name in fraction of second, without full unpacking. If file is stored on HDD, this works fine:

```
public class ZipMapper {
    private HashMap<String,ZipEntry> map;
    private ZipFile zf;

    public ZipMapper(File file) throws IOException {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        zf = new ZipFile(file);

        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> en = zf.entries();
        while(en.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry ze = en.nextElement();
            map.put(ze.getName(), ze);
        }
    }

    public Node getNode(String key) throws IOException {
        return Node.loadFromStream(zf.getInputStream(map.get(key)));
    }
}
```

But what can I do if program downloaded the zip file from Amazon S3 and has its InputStream (or byte array)? While downloading 1GB takes ~1 second, writing it to HDD may take some time, and it is slightly harder to handle multiple files since we don't have HDD garbage collector.

ZipInputStream does not allow to random access to entries.

It would be nice to create a virtual File in memory by byte array, but I couldn't find a way to.

Comment: Have you looked at the TrueZip library. It gives you access to ZIP entries like normal files, and if I remember correctly also allows access to remote zip files through http(s).

Answer (score 2):

You could mark the file to be deleted on exit.

If you want to go for an in-memory approach: Have a look at the new NIO.2 File API. Oracle provides a filesystem provider for zip/ jar and AFAIK [ShrinkWrap](http://exitcondition.alrubinger.com/2012/08/17/shrinkwrap-nio2/) provides an in-memory filesystem. You could try a combination of the two.

I've written some utility methods to copy directories and files to/from a Zip file using the NIO.2 File API (the library is Open Source):

Maven:

```
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.softsmithy.lib</groupId>  
    <artifactId>softsmithy-lib-core</artifactId>  
    <version>0.3</version>  
</dependency>
```

Tutorial:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/tutorial/nio-file/index.html

API: [CopyFileVisitor.copy](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/CopyFileVisitor.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29)

Especially [PathUtils.resolve](http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/nio/file/PathUtils.html#resolve%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path%29) helps with resolving paths across filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SecureBlackbox library, it allows ZIP operations on any seekable streams.

Comment: I downloaded the library, but couldn't find ANY documentation or reference on java/zip.

Comment: Yes. Java documentation is not ready, but most methods have the same naming as in .NET version of library, so you can check documentation at http://eldos.com/documentation/sbb/documentation/ref_cl_zipreader.html

Comment: Extract method can only write to `outputPath`. Can't get byte array or stream.

Comment: If outputPath is empty string, than extraction is done to Entry.ExtractionStream or handled via OnExtractionStreamNeeded event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using your OS in order to create "in memory" file system (i.e - RAM drive). 
In addition, take a look at the [FileSystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html)s API.

Comment: I think this is the only working solution. I ended up writing to HDD since it turned out to be blazingly fast in my case.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach: If the server has the file on disk (and possibly cached in RAM already): make it give you the file(s) directly. In other words, submit which files you need and then take care to extract and deliver these on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Blackbox library only has Extract(String name, String outputPath) method. Seems that it can randomly access any file in seekable zip-stream indeed, but it can't write result to byte array or return stream.

I couldn't find and documentation for ShrinkWrap. I couldn't find any suitable implementations of FileSystem/FileSystemProvider etc.

However, it turned out that Amazon EC2 instance I'm running (Large) somehow writes 1gb file to disk in ~1 second. So I just write file to the disk and use ZipFile.

If HDD would be slow, I think RAM disk would be the easiest solution.